# How do I select most popular objects, e.g list most read articles

Tags: api, facebook-opengraph

I am looking at creating a social reader app on which users can read articles I publish.

On the app home page, I want to list the most read articles.

Is there a way to do this client side using the FB API, or can I get the data from the FB API server side some how and store it?

or do I need to collate the read count in my own data store and create the list server side?

I am planning to have custom objects and actions and I essentially want a list of most popular objects by action

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do this client side using the FB API

No, I don't think so.

> or can I get the data from the FB API server side some how and store it?

Of course, just save it to a database and do your logic. For example, increment the count for each page in your database table when a user reads the article. Then use an SQL query that pulls the "TOP X"

```
select top 10 * from articletable order by NumRead asc
```

When a user makes a call to news.read an action instance id is returned inspect that for the respective article right after making the call

```
FB.api(
'/me/news.reads',
'post',
{ article: 'URL_TO_ARTICLE' },
function(response) {
   if (!response || response.error) {
      alert('Error occured');
      console.log(response.error);
   } else {
      FB.api(
       response.id, function(response) {
         var data = response['data'];
         var video = data['article']; 
         // Send to your database logic article['id'];
       });
   }
});
```

Or you skip the second API call altogether and just save the current page in your table and increment its count.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
How do I get the data from facebook in the first place? Do I have to make a call to the FB API per article? This could be quite an intensive task to loop through all articles and query FB on a regular basis

Comment: @AmitDesai Why loop when you could instead save the increment *as* each user makes the call. You are doing each instance once. At the end of it all you are not querying Facebook, but your own database for 10 ids of Graph objects, the cost in that call is minimal.